# SimonVT MenuDrawer drag menu with imageview

Tags: java, android, menu, drawer

I want to use menudrawer by SimonVt and it does exactly what I need. But the only problem is that I want to attach a `ImageView` to which I can drag to show/hide menu. I tried to set `setSlideDrawable` but it ain't working. 
I can do it by setting `onTouchListner` and translate my `ImageView` while dragging. But, I'm pretty sure if I'm using this library there should be some way of doing it without this hassle.

Comment: I'm still trying on it :(

Comment: Hey Hasandroid, have u found anything on it ?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I had a talk with SimonVT and he told me its not possible using using the library.